# how to fix a gridcontrol cell that should contain an image when there is not into the path?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I created a winform using devexpress gridcontrol. This control has an image column. this is ok but when There is no the image into the path, the gridcontrol can't show the results of the query. How can I fix it?
First of all. I créated this function to return a datatable:

```
public DataTable select_users_per_name(string name)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID_US", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("NAME_US", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("PIC_US", typeof(Image));
    try
    {
        using (cnn = new OracleConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cadcon_face))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cmd = new OracleCommand("USERS.PROC_SELECT_USER_PER_NAME", cnn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("REFCUR", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("NAMEUSER", OracleDbType.Varchar2, name, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Image foto;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                picture = Image.FromFile(Convert.ToString(dr["PIC_US"]));
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID_US"]), Convert.ToString(dr["NAME_US"]), new Bitmap(picture, new Size(50, 50)) });
            }
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        record_log(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

After I put this code into thw winform.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridcontrolUser.DataSource = select_users_per_name(txtUserName.Text);
    gridviewUser.Columns["PIC_US"].ColumnEdit = new RepositoryItemPictureEdit();
}
```

The column table into my database is PIC_US and it contains for example: D:\img_pictures\cont_3401418_n.jpg. The problema appears when there isn't the image. The gridcontrol doesn't show the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
try
{
    picture = Image.FromFile(Convert.ToString(dr["PIC_USUARIO"]));
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID_US"]), Convert.ToString(dr["Name_US"]), new Bitmap(pocture, new Size(50, 50)) });
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID_US"]), Convert.ToString(dr["Name_US"]), null });
}
```

Add this library

```
using System.IO;
```

Good Luck.